# Error when trying to build android APK with ionic cordova

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

So, I want to build an Android apk with the ionic angular framework. But it always got an error when I'm trying to build with `ionic cordova build android`
The error says : **Cannot find module '@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/utils'**

Then I tried to install the angular-devkit with `npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular` but it still got an error

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: devdacticApp@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler-cli@9.1.13
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!   dev @angular/compiler-cli@"~9.1.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^13.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@13.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR!   dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"^13.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

Here is my ionic info :

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16 
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.9.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 13.0.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : not installed
   @angular/cli                  : 9.1.13
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 3.3.2
   @capacitor/core : 2.4.0

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)
   Cordova Platforms : android 9.1.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 4 other plugins)     

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 1.5.0

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 
   NodeJS            : v16.13.1 
   npm               : 8.2.0
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Comment: install "npm i @angular/compiler-cli"

Comment: Still same error here